# Android SQLite "table has no column named" error

Tags: android, sqlite

I keep getting error that a column in my table cannot be found. Cannot figure out why this is happening. The column names appear to be spelled correctly. Any help is appreciated. Here is my DBAdapter class:

Comment: Can you point out the statement where this is occurring? Are you getting an exception, or just the error you cited? If you're getting an exception, what is it?

Comment: Seriously? You did not posted it as an answer with that repo!!! You better use comments for clarification.

Comment: Why it has +1? Table x has no column named y is asked 5 times a day! And answer is always the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you changed the `KEY_LONG` value since you've tested the Database?
If so try upgrading the DB version.

Hope it helped you.

Comment: THANK YOU! I just needed to update the database version.

Comment: You're welcome! I lost half a day once on that problem!